# Need to send notification in a batch of 1000

Tags: php, mysql, database, batch-processing

I have created notification application , now i want to send notification to batch of 1000 users, but as i am new i dont know how to create that batch.

this is my code to push notification.

```
<?php
include('header.php');

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '[API-KEY comes here]' );

$sql="SELECT * FROM user_data";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Error'.mysqli_error($conn));
$registrationIds=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $registrationIds[] = $row['allow'];
}
$ids=json_encode($registrationIds);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;


?>
```

Now i can push notification on to users but how can i send notification in batch of 1000 if i have 10000  users?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write a loop and send out the notification API calls in batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (assuming that you want to send batch of 1000 registration ids with every curl request):

```
$batch_size = 1000; // 1000 per request

$iterations = ceil(count($registrationIds) / $batch_size); // determine how many iterations are needed

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    $offset = $i * $batch_size;
    $batch_of_1000_user_ids = array_slice($registrationIds, $offset, $batch_size);

    // json_encode, prepare headers and send curl request
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will helps you.

```
    // Chunk of Array with 999 Records, I have not taken risk for 1000 users :D
    // Here $array is a collection of rows which you get from Table.
    $final_array = array_chunk($array, 999);

    // Loop for Every Sub Array and Send to FCM Server
    foreach($final_array as $array_of_chunk) {

        // Your code for sending notification...
        // $registrationIds = $array_of_chunk;

    }
```

You can see full code for PHP here [Send Firebase Notification to more than 1000 users at a time from PHP](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/0105fd8cb7678f3e4b7fef2cb313db0a).

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To execute a **PHP** script via command line or from batch file :

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;/FULLPATH/TOPHP/EXECUTABLE
php /FULLPATH/PHPSCRIPT.php 1>execution.log 2>executionError.log
```

To lunch multiple threads in **PHP**, follow this example :[PHP Multithread](https://github.com/Halayem/ANYEM/blob/master/ANYEM_CLIENT/anyem.client.tst/AnyemClientMultiThreadTest.php)
To install pthread, follow this [PTHREAD installation tutorial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php)

Comment: Please share more details. How does this answer ensure that batches of 1000 notification calls are sent?