# How to send push notification to more than 1000 users using firebase in Android?

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting following error message when sending push notification to more than 1000 users:

"firebase Number of messages on bulk (1082) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)"

I have googled the issue and found that FCM can send only 1000 message per request. 
Solution: Split sender list in php, but unfortunately I am new to php and unable to achieve the looping.

My php script is:

```
    <?php
        function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
        {
                $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
                $fields = array(
                         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                         'data' => $message,
                         'click_action' => ACTIVITY_CIRCULAR
                        );
                $headers = array(
                        'Authorization:key = <MY_KEY> ',
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                        );
           $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
        }

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databse_name");
        $sql = " Select Token From users";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $tokens = array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $message = array("message" => "Hi This Arbaz Alam And You are using Android App Thanks.");
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
        echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

Can you please help me in this regard and provide me a push_notification.php script that will split the users.

I have tried to split the message in chunks of 1000 but get no success:

```
    <?php
function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'data' => $message
        );

        $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = <MY-KEY>',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}


function send_message($tokens)
{
        $message = array("message" => "AKTU Even Semester Result is updated");
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
        echo $message_status;
}


$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");

$sql = " Select Token From users";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();

$num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_of_rows";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
                if(count($tokens) == 1000){
                        send_message($tokens);
                        $tokens = array();
                }
        }
}

send_message($tokens);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You can divide set of tokens as subset 1000 tokens each and then the function send_notification can be called for each 1000 tokens set. Determine the total number of tokens you have in your database and send to 1000 at once, then move onto the next set of 1000 and so on.

Comment: i know that i have to send message in chunks of 1000 but how can I achieve it as I have very little knowledge about php.

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of help you need?

Comment: @Nilesh I have added the new code in my comment but don't get success.

Comment: i follow your code and it's result shows Successful but i am not getting any  PUSH message..

Comment: @techDigi follow this link https://github.com/miskoajkula/Fcm for details.

Comment: Check here for full code : [Send Firebase Notification to more than 1000 users at a time from PHP](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/0105fd8cb7678f3e4b7fef2cb313db0a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52968379/1318946

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hello you can use array_chunk for send 1000 notification

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array("message" => "Hi This Arbaz Alam And You are using Android App Thanks.");

$regIdChunk=array_chunk($tokens,1000);

foreach($regIdChunk as $RegId){
     $message_status = send_notification($RegId, $message);
}
echo $message_status;
```

Please change this in your code.

Comment: please tell from where $RegId and $gcm_regid comes and what are they defines?

Comment: please check tokes array user theie by mistake i am print there

Comment: @JDTheRealHero i tried your code but i am getting : "registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

Comment: Please check this http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2017/07/create-custom-notification-in-andoid-using-fcm.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52968379/1318946